# Accidentially put aluminum moka pot on stove without water ... is it still usable?

Tags: moka

I was a bit tired this morning and accidentally put my moka pot (Bialetti Brikka, aluminum) on the stove with the water still in the top (for measuring the amount), instead of pouring it into the boiler.

Realized my mistake early enough, no burnt coffee or rubber, no smell. The moka didn't warp or anything. I let it cool down, re-filled it, works as expected.

Anyway, I'm a bit paranoid (especially regarding the health concerns with aluminum), so I wonder if there's any concern ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be totally fine - and [you aren’t the first person who did something like this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31514995#31514995).

Aluminum melts at a whopping 660C (933K) and while pure aluminum is chemically very reactive, the pot with its oxide layer is quite stable, so whatever you did will have left your Moka way below any temperature range where anything unwelcome may happen. Especially as you report that the rubber gasket is unharmed, and that would be the first part to suffer any heat damage.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that makes a lot of sense. I've been using it since and didn't notice any difference, luckily.