# Left on the stovetop without water -- do I need a new moka pot?

Tags: moka

I put my moka pot & coffee on the stove this morning and forgot to put water into the bottom. Definitely a strong burnt rubber and burnt coffee smell before I noticed it; the rubber gasket was warped and it stuck to the top part a bit while I was trying to remove it.

Would getting a replacement rubber gasket be good enough or is the aluminum body (and basket) damaged too at this point?

Answer (score 1):

We have an [almost identical Q/A](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/5134/accidentially-put-aluminum-moka-pot-on-stove-without-water-is-it-still-usabl?rq=1), just without a burnt gasket. In short, aluminum is very heat tolerant and unless you see some unexpected warping or other deformation (unlikely, I would assume), replacing the seal should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Stephie, it should be fine unless you see water leaking through a crack in the metal.

Clean the pot by boiling some purified water through it. Purified water is an excellent cleaning agent as it pulls and carries dissolveable compounds away.

You may want to consider finding a silicone gasket to replace the rubber one. The harder silicone materials can impart less odor/taste than synthetic rubber compounds.